# TestNg skipping @BeforeSuite and @BeforeClass when running in group

Tags: java, testng

When  running TestNg with **groups** it is skipping @BeforeClass and @BeforeSuite methods. however running without group it execute @BeforeClass and @BeforeSuite

Code :

```
class TestStructure {

 @BeforeClass
 public void loadData() {
  System.out.println("loaded");
 }

 @BeforeSuite
 public void loadSysData() {
  System.out.println("loaded2");
 }
}


class Test extends TestStructure
{

    @Test(groups={"UAP"})
    public void test1
    {
     System.out.println("Test 2");
    }

}
```

The `testng.xml` file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="UAP suite" parallel="false" thread-count="1" verbose="1">
   <listeners>
      <listener class-name="com.module.listener.TestNGListener" />
   </listeners>

   <test name="TestSet 1" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
      <groups>
         <run>
            <include name="UAP" />
         </run>
      </groups>
      <classes>
         <class name="Test" />
      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

If I remove group from the xml then `@BeforeClass` and `@BeforeSuite` are executed.
Please help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two options you need to consider in order to resolve this issue.

1. Add an attribute `alwaysRun=true` for all your beforeXXX & afterXXX methods. If you want these methods to run irrespective of group being tested
2. If you would like to associate beforeXXX & afterXXX to only specific set of groups, in that case you need to bind these methods to that group using attribute `groups`.

Based on your use case, you need update your annotations to either

`@BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true)` and `@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun=true)`

or

`@BeforeClass(groups={"UAP"})` and `@BeforeSuite(groups={"UAP"})`

Hope this answers your question.

For further Reference - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Comment: Why on earth is this the design Cedric? https://stackoverflow.com/users/162410/cedric-beust

Answer (score 1):

If the Top rated solution dont work please follow this

1)Try to run the Groups with excluding the groups you don't want to execute instead of including the Groups you want to execute

2)Instead leave `<exclude>` value as blank

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="UAP suite" parallel="false" thread-count="1" verbose="1">
   <listeners>
      <listener class-name="com.module.listener.TestNGListener" />
   </listeners>

   <test name="TestSet 1" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
      <groups>
         <run>
            <exclude name="" />
         </run>
      </groups>
      <classes>
         <class name="Test" />
      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```